# WIX detect uninstall or change click in Add/Remove programs

Tags: wix

I'm working with WIX 3.7. I have a custom managed bootstrapper based on 
BryanJ source code: http://bryanpjohnston.com/2012/09/28/custom-wix-managed-bootstrapper-application/

The installer works fine but I want to detect the pressed button in the Add/Remove programs. I mean whether the user wants to Repair or Change the installed application. At the moment I just open a window with possible options (for uninstall and change).

Thanks

Comment: Bob's answer is the way to go and is actually the method I use for detecting uninstalls via ARP in my production bootstrapper. Must have had a brain fart before posting my initial answer because I tried looking for how I detect it in my own code and missed it. Although you could use my solution, Bob's is much better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the `LaunchAction` enum that's passed in the `Command.Action` property:

```
public enum LaunchAction
{
    Unknown,
    Help,
    Layout,
    Uninstall,
    Install,
    Modify,
    Repair,
    UpdateReplace,
    UpdateReplaceEmbedded,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I *think* the way it works is that the bootstrapper puts the appropriate uninstall and repair commands in the in registry here:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\<productCode>
```

So for example, when I look at the WiX 3.7 entry in this location, it has a registry key called `ModifyPath` with the value `"C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{963ac4b4-a882-4471-8db9-c4adc7b42dc4}\WiX37.exe" /modify`.

Therefore you could parse the command line for the `/modify` switch for repairs and similarly the `/uninstall` switch for uninstalls.

Comment: It may also be the case that the bootstrapper engine does this for you and it is just a matter of subscribing to the appropriate event and checking the event args, but if that is the case I am not sure how to get that info.